# Seekbar lags when big picture in imageView

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have a problem with seekBar when I load a big image from gallery in my imageView.
When I move seekBar, it moves with lags but not smooth.

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: @Nilesh I edit my question

Comment: r you testing on a device or emulator? because emulator is slow be default

Comment: @MounirElfassi I test it on my smartphome, native emulator and genymotion. And I have dat lag..